# How can I delete a plugin from wordpress plugin directory?

Tags: wordpress

Actually I have just uploaded my plugin into WordPress plugin directory.For some causes and give it something new look I just want to delete or deactivate that plugin from directory.

Can anyone tell how to deactivate or delete the plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write directly to plugins@wordpress.org and ask the plugin deletion, there is no way that you can do it.